# taskdef class com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport cannot be found Following "The java web services tutorial"

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I saw the same issue in many different locations and even after a good portion of googling, I could not resolve it. What I am trying to do (the bigger picture) is to go through [The java web services tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/), which seems at points out of sync,

Specially [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/), when I try to compile, I get the following message:

> C:\javaeetutorial5\examples\jaxws\common\targets.xml:26: taskdef class **com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport** cannot be found

I have tried many different combinations of placing jars or changing environment variables, but with no result. Any successful stories?

The full build error message is the following:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\javaeetutorial5\examples\jaxws\helloservice\build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>
> C:\javaeetutorial5\examples\jaxws\common\targets.xml:26: taskdef A class needed by class com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport cannot be found: org/apache/tools/ant/DynamicConfigurator
>
> using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\lib\tools.jar]
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

And the corresponding **taskdef**:

```
<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath refid="jaxws.classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Also a peek into the endorsement directory:

```
C:\javaeetutorial5\kschneid>cd %JAVA_HOME%

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23>dir lib\endorsed
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is AAAA-BBBB

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\lib\endorsed

25/02/2011  09:34    <DIR>          .
25/02/2011  09:34    <DIR>          ..
25/02/2011  09:34           105,134 jaxb-api.jar
25/02/2011  09:33            54,476 jaxws-api.jar
               2 File(s)        159,610 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  110,907,056,128 bytes free

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23>
```

Comment: What does your `<taskdef>` look like? Include the classpath you're using.

Comment: @kschneid. I am sorry for not including all the details. Since many people start with this tutorial, I thought we'd meet the same obstacles. Updating

Comment: ...and how is `jaxws.classpath` defined?

Comment: ...and you should also specify which version of JAX-WS and Ant you're using...

Comment: about jaxws.classpath. I do not know even if it is set (I was following a tutorial with no specific mention and I am new in this technology). Also I have downloaded JAXWS2.2.3

Answer (score 22):

You can fix the problem in Netbeans x.y as follows:

1. Go to Tools->Options->Java->Ant.
2. Click on "Add JAR/ZIP..." under the Classpath section
3. Navigate to "C:\Program Files\NetBeans x.y\enterprise\modules\ext\metro\"
4. Select all files.
5. Click OK, and try the import/regenerate again.

where x.y = 7.1, 7.2, 8.0 etc

Comment: Do not currently have the resources to check, could someone else with the same problem try and inform?

Comment: You don't have the resources to check for what?

Comment: I do not have the time to check you solution to see if it is true (download netbeans install it and follow the steps). If someone else can confirm it, I can choose the answer as correct :-)

Comment: Worked with Netbeans 8.2 on Centos 7. I installed my netbeans in the folder netbeans-8.2rc inside my home filder, so the complete path to the jars is /home/my_user/netbeans-8.2rc/enterprise/modules/ext/metro/

Comment: New Path: "C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\metro"

Comment: This also works with Netbeans 12.6. New path: C:\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\metro

Answer (score 13):

Well, apparently a link to a website with the [solution](http://loudsight.net/how-to/solved_taskdef_class_comsuntoolswsantwsimport_cannot_be_found.html) to this issue is unacceptable, so I'll paste the answer here:

```
<property name="BUILD_LIBS" location="C:/Projects/Build/Libs/" />

<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${BUILD_LIBS}/jaxws-ri/lib/jaxws-tools.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

The issue is due to the relevant [jaxws](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.1/) jar not being in the class path see the pathelement node above. Adding the jar to the classpath resolves the issue.

Comment: since the solution link is now a dead end, it's kind of nice that you put the code here!

Answer (score 9):

The `<wsimport>` ant task is not included in the JDK, even though there is a wsimport.exe which does exactly the same.

If you really want the ant task, you can download jaxws-ri and use the 23(!) jars in the lib folder.

Or you can use this workaround by calling **wsimport.exe**:

```
<target name="generate-client" >
    <exec executable="${java.home}/../bin/wsimport">
        <arg line="-keep -d build/classes -p ebay.apis -s src -wsdllocation http://localhost:7070/Ebay?wsdl eBaySvc.wsdl"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 4):

I fully support non-IDE development, especially when trying to learn something ;). Try starting with this simple build file (use the actual location of your JAX-WS RI install):

```
<project name="jaxws-tutorial" default="wsimport">

    <property name="jaxws.home" location="D:/jaxws-ri-2_2_1"/>

    <path id="wsimport.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${jaxws.home}/lib" includes="jaxws-tools.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport" classpathref="wsimport.classpath"/>

    <target name="wsimport">
        <wsimport>
            <arg value="-version"/>
        </wsimport>
    </target>

</project>
```

If you just run `ant`, you should see some output like the following:

```
wsimport:
 [wsimport] Consider using <depends>/<produces> so that wsimport won't do unnecessary compilation
 [wsimport] JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-b01-
```

Since it looks like you're using Java 6, pay attention to ["Running on JDK6"](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.1/docs/jaxws-tools.html#running_on_jdk6).

Comment: I feel I am close, but not there yet (added how the endorsement location looks in the question body above), I have the following output:
BUILD FAILED
c:\javaeetutorial5\kschneid\build.xml:9: taskdef A class needed by class com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport cannot be found: org/apache/tools/ant/DynamicConfigurator
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\jaxws-tools.jar;C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\jaxws-rt.jar;C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\jaxws-api.jar;C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\jsr181-api.jar;C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\jsr250-api.jar;C:\Sun\jaxws-ri\lib\saaj-api.jar;...]

Total time: 0 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I changed the `classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport"` to `classname="com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport"`, which fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

To get past this error we need to use Tools->Options, click Miscellaneous, and in the Ant tab use Add Jar/ZIP to locate and add the libraries  [webservices-tools.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadwebservicestoolsjar.htm) and [webservices-rt.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadwebservicesrt12jar.htm)  in the directory

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

I download the JAVA-WS library from [official site](https://jax-ws.java.net/)
I put it on extra-lib directory. This directory is on the same level of build.xml.
On build.xml I copy from jaxws-build.xml the Ant task named “wsimport-init” and I modify it as in the follow mode:

```
...
    <target name="wsimport-init" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}/jax-ws"/>
        <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.Ant.WsImport">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="./extra-lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
    </target>
...
```

Reference: http://www.staniscia.net/989-resolve-the-portable-problem-of-netbean-jax-ws-libraries-for-web-service-clients/

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which does not satisfy me at all: 
Installed netbeans which takes care of joining things together. Still the command line does not work (so that means that it is compartmentalised the environment which is good). I can follow up the tutorial, but I still believe that everything should be done from the command line (was there too much Unix in my diet?)

Comment: i think i'm having the same experience. i was hoping to just use the ant build.xml created by netbeans to create my ws that depends on other ws. but i'm having this issue below. would love to hear if you got your situation resolved.

Comment: Unfortunately I had to abandon the (educational) project, this is the reason I have not chosen an answer up until now. What I've got out of it is that the documentation on Sun's site is outdated. At some consumption scenarios I encountered later on, I happened to use RESTful interfaces, so I did not had the necessity to dwell into web services. Will update when something changes...

Answer (score 0):

Better still, you can use the command line tool wsimport to generate the jar or files

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

generate the files into the build/classes folder, you can then reference it from there with ant javac

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE and facing this issue, here is something that worked for me.
Go to : Window > Preferences.
Find the Ant option on the left side.

Expand it and you will find ANT Runtime. Select that option and check the jars included in the Classpath tab.

Select the Add External Jar's option. Now go to the ant home folder in your system. Go to the lib folder and add all the jars / missing jar files.

this will resolve the missing dependency for ant-build.

Hope That Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after testing Netbeans 11 and then going back to Netbeans 8.2. The solution was the file

```
ProjectName\nbproject\private\private.properties
```

that one had an entry

```
user.properties.file=XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\11.0\\build.properties
```

changing it back to the correct installation

```
user.properties.file=XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.2\\build.properties
```

solved the problem. For some projects Netbeans popped up a dialogbox "The project ProjectName uses `build.properties` from another Netbeans installation", then click "Use this installation".