# WsImport ant task and JDK 6

Tags: java, web-services, ant, jax-ws, wsimport

I am trying to use jax-ws to generate web service proxy classes, using the wsimport ant task, similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091573/taskdef-class-com-sun-tools-ws-ant-wsimport-cannot-be-found-following-the-java-w), with the following follow-on question:

As I understand it, more recent versions of JDK 1.6 include jax-ws and the WsImport ant task is defined in the JDK's tools.jar file.

**Why does ant not find this automatically?**

**Why does eclipse not find this automatically as well?**

I found a few references to using jax-ws with JDK 6, but these seem to be based on copying a separately downloaded jax-ws library and dropping it into the JDK ext folder (which I assume is no longer required given that it is actually bundled with the JDK now).

**What is the proper way to use the wsimport task with a version of JDK 1.6 that already includes jax-ws?**

My build XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="wsproxy">
    <taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport" />
    <target name="wsgentest">
        <wsimport
            wsdl="http://localhost/Service?wsdl"
            destdir="bin-gen"
            sourcedestdir="src-gen"
            keep="true"
            verbose="true"
            package="com.ws">
        </wsimport>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the WsImport class that is in the JDK is not actually an ant task, but the actual wsimport command line tool.  I misread the package name as well: com.sun.tools.internal.ws.

The actual ant task is available in webservices-tools.jar in the metro package [here](http://metro.java.net/2.1.1/).  You will need to drop it in the ant lib directory.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, what is bundled with the JDK6 is the *binary tool* itself, not the actual Ant task.

I have Java 1.6.0_31 in my dev box, although a slightly special one (JRockit R28.2.3), and this is the only way I have found to use `wsimport` task properly.

1. Download a suitable version of JAX-WS from the official site. With JDK6 it should be a version up to [2.1.10](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.1.10/). If you try to use version 2.2+, you will have a classpath conflict.
2. Install the JAR contents with `java -jar {jaxwsJarName}`, whatever name it is. This command will create a `[jaxws-ri]` folder.
3. Copy the contents of `[jaxws-ri/lib]` folder in the location of choice. In spite of the size, I like to have the external libraries along my own projects, to ensure anyone may be able to compile and package the code with no external artifacts.
4. Create the `taskdef` item and the `wsimport` task in your build file.

This is my `taskdef` item:

```
<taskdef
    name="wsimport"
    classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">

    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}/jaxws-ri-2.1.10">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

And this is my `wsimport` task:

```
<target name="generate-code">
    <wsimport
        wsdl="${wsdl.dir}/${wsdl.name}-${wsdl.version}.wsdl"
        sourcedestdir="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${build.debug.dir}"
        package="${generated.code.package}">

        <depends file="${wsdl.dir}/${wsdl.name}-${wsdl.version}.wsdl" />
        <produces dir="${build.debug.dir}" />
    </wsimport>
</target>
```